# Animated Impostor

Tags: textures, animation

I need to create explosions and smoke, but as the particle does not interact with the environment (there are in the background) I was thinking of using the Animated Impostor technique (or animated textures):
Make the animation in Blender render it as a a bunch of images and render the animation either using a 3D texture (and updating the z value) either using a 2D texture (and moving the uv coordinates).

My concern is, the rendered animation represent about 25Mb of data (for a 512x512 pic with 30fps). So it might be not an optimized solution?

Is it the way to render animated textures?

Comment: Does it need to be 512x512?  If a size of 25mb is a concern then you might be targetting lower-end hardware, so maybe you should consider a lower resolution.  Drop it to 256x256 and it's quarter the size.  Animate it at 10fps rather than 30fps and it's one-third the size.  Combine the two and it's down to just over 2mb.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point it start to reduce the quality and does not render well.